# Is this an accurate parse of "as the weather was nasty he remained at home"?

Tags: clauses

> As the weather was nasty he remained at home.

He - subject

remained - predicate

at home - adverbial modifier of place

as the weather was nasty - adverbial modifier of cause

Are they correct? Or maybe **"was nasty"** should be a predicate?

Comment: Please write informative titles. That title is as far as I go. You write a better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check the term predicate. Normally a sentence consists of a subject and a statement about the subject. This statement is called predicate in Latin grammar. "remained" is no statement as it is incomplete. The predicate is "remained at home".

In English grammars today the grammar term predicate is seldom used. Today the structure of sentences is mostly described with the terms subject, verb, object, complement (referring to subject/object), adverbial part.

As verb is a word class the term verb should not be used as sentence part as well.
It would be better to use the term verbal part when the part of sentence is meant.

You use predicate for verb or more exactly for verbal part and that is not correct.

In your sentence you have a main clause (he remained at home) and a subclause (As the weather was nasty) and in your description of the sentence structure you should clearly show this.

Comment: And what about "as the weather was nasty..." - is it an adverbial modifier of cause?

Comment: First a all it is a subordinate clause with the conjunction as.

Comment: Like all clauses, a subordinate clause should have a subject and a predicate,right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: So in subclause the predicate is "was nasty"